# Partición de Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Estoy terminando de cursar una Maestría de Minería de datos y tuve que comprar una notebook en estos días porque se me rompió la que estaba usando. Dentro de mi presupuesto compre una con win 10 home i7 7ma generacion 12 gb 1 Tb. Necesito usar Linux tambien (ubuntu) Pregunta: la particiono? O me paso a win pro y uso maquina virtual?. Tengo miedo de partirla y que el windows se me "pierda" (me pasó con la notebook anterior...) Gracias!

Comment: instala Ubuntu como sub-sistema: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6 y tienes la potencia de GNU/Linux sin romper cosas del windows :D

Comment: Si redimensionas la particion de win con un programa especifico no deberea romperlo. El problema es que al ser un pc nuevo traera bios uefi, y eso da problemas para hacer un arranque dual de los dos sistemas. Pero si no recuerdo mal el instalador de ubuntu te da la opcion de instalarlo junto con win en su misma particion aunqe eso resta algo de velocidad.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta por no ajustarse al [alcance definido para el sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ni parece tratar acerca de otros temas [discutidos por la comunidad](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/161/127).

Comment: Y si instalas Virtual Box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu es muy facil de instalar junto a W10, lo pimero que debes hacer es crer una particion con tu windows utilizando la herramienta "Crear y formatear particiones de disco duro", una vezla creas arrancas la pc desde usb y cuando te pregunte donde quieres instalar Ubuntu le dices que en la particion que creaste.